# How to get the file name without a certain line of text in the directory?

Tags: shell

I'm running some experiments that will output the results into corresponding files. If the result of the experiment is successful, the text of `completed all` will be in the file. I want to output the cases where the experiment was unsuccessful, that is, the sentence "completed all" does not exist in the file.
The different experimental results can be distinguished by the file name. With `ls` I can get all the files and with `grep` I can get the successful ones. Subtraction can get the failing filename.

But I found, that all filenames are always output.

1. When I validate using two simple arrays, the result is correct. This shows that the subtraction function is correct.
2. When I output all the file names alone, or output the correct file names, the output is also correct.
3. But the code below, when run together, outputs all the filenames.

```
CURRENT_DIR=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd)
ChampSim_path=$CURRENT_DIR/..
cd $CURRENT_DIR/$1


all=$(ls -q * | wc -l)

good=$(grep "ChampSim completed all CPUs" * | wc -l)

good_trace_prefetcher=($(grep  -Rl "ChampSim completed all CPUs" *  ))

all_trace_prefetcher=($(ls -q * ))

# echo  ${good_trace_prefetcher[@]}
# echo   ${all_trace_prefetcher[@]}

# exit
# arry_list1=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
# arry_list2=(3 5 8)

arry_list1=${all_trace_prefetcher[@]}
arry_list2=${good_trace_prefetcher[@]}
 
declare -a diff_list
t=0
flag=0

# echo arry_list1=${arry_list1[@]}
# echo arry_list2=${arry_list2[@]}
 
for list1_num in "${arry_list1[@]}"
do
    # echo list1_num is ${list1_num}
    for list2_num in "${arry_list2[@]}"
    do
        # echo list2_num is ${list2_num}
        if [[ "${list1_num}" == "${list2_num}" ]]; then
            flag=1
            break
        fi
    done
    if [[ $flag -eq 0 ]]; then
        diff_list[t]=$list1_num
        t=$((t+1))
    else
        flag=0
    fi
done
echo diff_list=${diff_list[@]}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using `bash` (or possibly `ksh`), so why not include a tag for the shell you are using. There will be more "followers" for `bash` and hence more eyes on your problem. Unfortunately, it's getting to the TLDR size, and without test inputs and expected outputs it's hard to know where to start. (IMHO). Good luck. (`grep` solution looks good below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered `grep -vl 'searchstring' files`? (Or `-vil` if you want case insensitive matching).

Example:

```bash
$ echo 'completed all' > f1
$ echo 'completed all' > f2
$ echo 'completed all' > f3
$ echo 'error' > f4        
$ echo 'error' > f5
$ grep -vl 'completed all' *
f4
f5
```